# kindle paperwhite 2 check email over 3g

Tags: amazon, kindle-paperwhite

I am still unable to get an answer to this question: Can I check email and do other web-browsing activities with the kindle paperwhite 2 (of course with poor quality viewing experience) over 3g? I read 3g enables access only to wikipedia and amazon sites or that at least the access to other sites is limited to some data amount.

There is a similar question ([Internet access on the 3G Amazon Kindles?](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/questions/182/internet-access-on-the-3g-amazon-kindles)) but I would like to know an exact information on how it is with Kindle paperwhite 2 (I will buy it probably in Germany).

Comment: Moved from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27196526/kindle-paperwhite-2-check-email-over-3g?noredirect=1#comment42896120_27196526

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a Kindle Paperwhite 3G, free web browsing in 3G mode is limited. You can access only the Amazon website and Wikipedia via 3G wireless. For accessing other websites, you need to use a Wi-Fi connection. [source](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-browser-on-your-kindle-paperwhite.html)

For a very update-to-date answer, I suggest to ask amazon support for further info.